# How to change the value of an input inside of a frame with VBScript

Tags: input, vbscript, frame, getelementbyid, frameset

I want to make a script which will open IE and automatically fill in inputs in a form on an external website. The inputs I want filled-in are placed inside of a frame. So the `getElementByID` won't work here.

I've made my own test site to use the script on. Later on I will implement it to the other one but I wanted to start off simple. This is the site the script will open:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
  <frame name="menu" src="menu.html">
  <frame name="form" src="form.html">
  <frame name="application" src="application.html">
</frameset>

</html>
```

This is an example of `form.html` (It doesnt have to submit anything yet it's just  a test):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>        
  <body>
    <div class="login">
     <form action='' method='POST' id='nameform'>
       Username: <input type='text' name='user' id='user' value=""><br>   
       Password: <input type='password' name='pswrd' id='pswrd' value=""><br>    
      <input name='submit' type='submit' value='submit' id='submit'><br>
     </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And last but not least here is my VBScript:

```vb
Call Main

Function Main
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")

    IE.Visible = True

    IE.Navigate "http://example.com"
    Wait IE
    With IE.Document 
        .getElementByID("user").value = "CoolUsername123"
        .getElementByID("pswrd").value = "BestPasswordEver321"
    End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 500
    Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

This code works fine on other sites, I've used it on trello.com before. However this site doesn't use frames and I think this might be the problem.

I've tried to use this code as well:

```
Call Main

Function Main
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")

    IE.Visible = True

    IE.Navigate "http://example.com"
    Wait IE
    With IE.Document 
    set frame = IE.document.getElementsByName("form")(0)
        frame.contentwindow.document.getElementByID("user").value = "CoolUsername123"
        frame.contentwindow.document.getElementByID("pswrd").value = "BestPasswordEver321"
    End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 500
    Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

I have also tried:

```
IE.Document.Frames("form").Document.All("user").Value = "CoolUsername123"
```

I don't get the error anymore but there's also no value in the inputs

Answer (score 1):

First get the frame named "form" from the page. Since it has only name, we can use the [getElementsByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438(v=vs.85).aspx) method and get the first element of the returned collection:

```
set frame = IE.document.getElementsByName("form")(0)
```

Now access the form fields using the [contentWindow property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533692(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
 frame.contentwindow.document.getElementByID("user").value = "CoolUsername123"
 frame.contentwindow.document.getElementByID("pswrd").value = "BestPasswordEver321"
```

Comment: I've tried using your method but it didn't work. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong with the code or if the code just simply doesn't work in VBScript.

Comment: You could edit  your question and add the code you are using now so that we can check and see if it works for us.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Was asking if you can add your existing code which does not work to your question. click the edit button beneath your question to add to it.

Comment: I'm using the code from VBScript that's in my question to try and get the elements that are displayed in the HTML examples

Comment: I have used the same html page you showed in your question, and the VBScript in my answer and it is working for me. The VBScript in your question was not working to start with(so your question). Did you change your VBScript to what was in my answer?

Comment: Comment out the `With IE.Document` and `End With` lines.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It's telling me that it's having trouble to find: set frame = IE.document.getElementByID("form")(0)

Comment: it is `IE.document.getElementsByName("form")(0)` . You have get the frame by __Name__ not __Id__

Comment: I've tried multiple ones myself. I've tired: getElementsByName, getElementByTagName and getElementById. None of them seems to work.

Comment: what exactly is the error message? And you are still testing with the "form.html" page, right?

Comment: The error is written in dutch so I'll try my best to translate it. It says: "This method isn't supported by this object: 'frame.contentwindow.Document.getElementByID', it also gives me a code: "800A01B6".

Comment: I don't know what is happening. Can you try `IE.Document.Frames("form").Document.All("user").Value = "CoolUsername123"` .

Comment: I don't get the error anymore after I used `IE.Document.Frames("form").Document.All("user").Value = "CoolUsername123"`. But there's also no value in the inputs.